# Group cohomology of Galois group of finite extension of finite fields

Tags: finite-groups, galois-theory, finite-fields, group-cohomology, galois-extensions

Let $E/F$ be a finite extension of finite fields; hence, it is a cyclic Galois extension, so let the Galois group be $G$. Hilbert's Theorem 90 states that $H^1(G, E^{\times})=0$.

My question is: How to show that $H^n(G, E^{\times})=0,\forall n\ge 2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $G$ is a finite cyclic group, its cohomology is periodic: $H^{n+2}(G,M)\cong
H^n(G,M)$ for all $n\ge1$. This proves your equation for odd $n$. But this fails
for $n=0$. In this case $H^2(G,M)\cong{\hat H}^0(G,M)$, the $0$-th Tate cohomology group.
This is defined to be $M^G/T(M)$ where $M^G=H^0(G,M)$ is the set of $G$-invariant elements
of $M$ and $T(M)$ is the image of $M$ under the trace map $T:m\mapsto\sum_{g\in G}m^g$.

There are various ways of proving $\hat H^0(G,E^\times)\cong H^2(G,E^\times)$ is trivial.
First, by direct computation: when $|F|=q$ and $|E|=q^n$, $E^\times$ is cyclic
of order $q^n-1$, $(E^\times)^G$ has order $q-1$ and $T$ is powering by $(q^n-1)/(q-1)$.
Second, by the theory of the Herbrand quotient, as $E^\times$ is a finite group,
$|H^2(G,E^\times)|=|H^1(G,E^\times)|$. Third, $H^2(G,E^\times)$ is a subgroup
of the Brauer group of $F$, which is trivial by Wedderburn's theorem on
finite division rings.